# The Name of a Special Matrix Whose Entries $A_{ij} = j^i$

Tags: matrices, terminology

I heard that the matrix A whose entries $A_{ij} = j^i$
is a special one and has a name. Could you please help with its name?

Below is an example of a 4x4 matrix of this special type:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 4 & 9 & 16 \\ 1 & 8 & 27 & 64\\1 & 16 & 81 & 256\\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Well, for starters it's a special case of a Vandermonde matrix, where the $i$-th row is the $i$-th power of the first row.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You can find more about such matrices, their properties and their use at Mathworld, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VandermondeMatrix.html, or in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you both! I will search about this Vandermonde matrix.